# java stream make map after two different filters

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

It should return a Map.
Keys of this Map should be the Strings "transversion" and "transition", and the values of the Map should be lists of SNP objects. "Transitions" are changes between A<->G and C<->T and "transversions" are changes A<->C, G<->T, A<->T and C<->G.

How should I make the two filters?

```
public class StreamAssignment {

    private static final List<Snp> SNP_COLLECTION = Snp.getSnpCollection();
    private static final String[] SNP_DATA = new String[14];

    static {
        SNP_DATA[0] = "100273;A;G;0.0123";
        SNP_DATA[1] = "100275;A;C;0.00323";
        SNP_DATA[2] = "117807;T;G;0.1915";
        SNP_DATA[3] = "162889;C;G;8.72E-4";
        SNP_DATA[4] = "190199;T;C;0.1019";
        SNP_DATA[5] = "277614;A;G;0.0168";
        SNP_DATA[6] = "372778;C;A;4.24E-5";
        SNP_DATA[7] = "417752;A;G;1.8474E-10";
        SNP_DATA[8] = "478808;A;G;1.535689E-8";
        SNP_DATA[9] = "556920;T;G;0.1097";
        SNP_DATA[10] = "676255;G;C;0.0016672";
        SNP_DATA[11] = "667280;A;G;0.00287";
        SNP_DATA[12] = "719876;C;A;0.006649";
        SNP_DATA[13] = "828771;A;C;0.097706";
    }

    public static Map<String, List<Snp>> getTransversionsTransitions() {
        Map<String, List<Snp>> result;
        result = SNP_COLLECTION.stream().filter();


        return null;
    }
}
```

snp class

```
package nl.bioinf.appdesign.d_streams_lambdas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Snp {
    private final long position;
    private final char reference;
    private final char alternative;
    private final double minorAlleleFrequency;

    public Snp(long position, char reference, char alternative, double minorAlleleFrequency) {
        this.position = position;
        this.reference = reference;
        this.alternative = alternative;
        this.minorAlleleFrequency = minorAlleleFrequency;
    }

    public long getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public char getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public char getAlternative() {
        return alternative;
    }

    public double getMinorAlleleFrequency() {
        return minorAlleleFrequency;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Snp{" +
                "position=" + position +
                ", reference=" + reference +
                ", alternative=" + alternative +
                ", minorAlleleFrequency=" + minorAlleleFrequency +
                '}';
    }

    public final static List<Snp> getSnpCollection() {
        List<Snp> snps = new ArrayList<>();
        snps.add(new Snp(100273, 'A', 'G', 0.0123));
        snps.add(new Snp(100275, 'A', 'C', 0.00323));
        snps.add(new Snp(117807, 'T', 'G', 0.1915));
        snps.add(new Snp(162889, 'C', 'G', 0.000872));
        snps.add(new Snp(190199, 'T', 'C', 0.1019));
        snps.add(new Snp(277614, 'A', 'G', 0.0168));
        snps.add(new Snp(372778, 'C', 'A', 0.0000424));
        snps.add(new Snp(417752, 'A', 'G', 1.8474e-10));
        snps.add(new Snp(478808, 'A', 'G', 1.535689e-8));
        snps.add(new Snp(556920, 'T', 'G', 0.1097));
        snps.add(new Snp(676255, 'G', 'C', 1.6672e-3));
        snps.add(new Snp(667280, 'A', 'G', 0.00287));
        snps.add(new Snp(719876, 'C', 'A', 0.006649));
        snps.add(new Snp(828771, 'A', 'C', 0.097706));
        return snps;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question providing the Snp class implementation? Besides, I didn't quite understand the purpose of the array SNP_DATA

Comment: I have added the Snp class

Comment: Thank you. Could you maybe edit the question to elaborate the SNP_DATA array and the purpose of those strings (100273;A;G;0.0123)?

Comment: I need to make this for a school assignment, that code was already in there. I don't know the purpose either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Snp` class doesn't contain information about whether it's a transition or transversion, you would need a wrapper class. I'll omit that, but it just needs to have a `String type` property, `Snp snp` property, and a factory method (let's call it parse).

```
result = SNP_COLLECTION.stream()
        // do your filtering based on string values
        .map(SnpWrapper::parse) // String to Snp conversion
        // do your filtering based on Snp values
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Wrapper::getType,
                Collectors.mapping(Wrapper::getSnp, Collectors.toList())
        ));
```

Edit: the wrapping is actually not needed. You'll just need to provide a utility method. That can be placed in `Snp`, or as a private method in your current class. Let's assume it's the latter and it's named `getSnpType`:

```
result = SNP_COLLECTION.stream()
        // do your filtering based on string values
        .map(Snp::parse) // or whatever you have for String -> Snp
        // do your filtering based on Snp values
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StreamAssignment::getSnpType));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I think I don't really get what you would do for the .map parse method. I did make some code to get the snp type. public static String getSnpType(Snp snp){ if (snp.getReference() == 'A'){ if (snp.getAlternative() == 'G'){ return "Transitions";}}if (snp.getReference() == 'G'){if (snp.getAlternative() == 'A'){return "Transitions";}}if (snp.getReference() == 'A'){if (snp.getAlternative() == 'G'){return "Transitions";}}if (snp.getReference() == 'A'){if (snp.getAlternative() == 'G'){return "Transitions";}}return "transversions";}

Comment: So know if I do: SNP_COLLECTION.stream().forEach(w -> System.out.println(getSnpType(w))); I get either the word Transitions or transersions

Comment: Oh nice, with just this code: result = SNP_COLLECTION.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StreamAssignment::getSnpType)); I get the results I wanted

Comment: You're right. I used `SNP_COLLECTION` where I was planning on using `SNP_DATA`, but you don't need to parse it anymore, you've already done that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could concat your two chars `reference` & `alternative` to a string and use regex to check for `transition` or `transversion`. Something like

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

....


public static Map<String, List<Snp>> getTransversionsTransitions() {
    BiFunction<Character,Character,String> func =
            (a,b) -> (""+a+b).matches("AG|GA|CT|TC") ? "Transitions":"Transversions";
    return SNP_COLLECTION.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(snp -> func.apply(snp.getReference(),snp.getAlternative())));
}
```